# Instagram API authentification Rails 2017 request the access_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, instagram, instagram-api

**How can I download data from a url without being redirected to it?**

I have manage to get the authetification from instagram API working with the following code:

1. the user click on the button and logs in on the instagram log in page.
2. The user is redirected to my url
3. Because of the Code param in the url, some javascript is triggered to submit the form with the data to the api
4. I get redirected to the instagram api with the json data

This redirects me to the instagram api with the Json data but I'm not sure how I can use/download the information.

I'm sure this is not the best way to do it but I have tried many things and that's the only way I could get it to work.

```
 <a href=<%="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=#{ENV['CLIENT_ID']}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/edit&response_type=code"%>>Link my instagram account</a>
            <% if params[:code] %>
            <form id="target" method="post" action="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token">
              <div>
                <input type="text" name="client_id" value=<%= ENV['CLIENT_ID']%> hidden="true">
                <input type="text" name="client_secret" value=<%= ENV['CLIENT_SECRET']%> hidden="true">
                <input type="text" name="grant_type" value="authorization_code" hidden="true">
                <input type="text" name="redirect_uri" value="http://localhost:3000/edit" hidden="true">
                <input type="text" name="code" value=<%= params[:code]%> hidden="true" >
              </div>
            </form>
            <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with the following code indeed:

So first you need this request to get the first code:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=#{ENV['CLIENT_ID']}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000&response_type=code
```

Then use the code in the following post request to get access token and the data:

```
result = HTTParty.post("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
  {
    :body =>  { "client_id" => ENV['CLIENT_ID'], "client_secret" => ENV['CLIENT_SECRET'],
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
    "redirect_uri" => 'http://localhost:3000', "code" => session[:code] },
    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}
  })
```

In order to find the user id, simply add the following:

```
result.parsed_response["user"]["id"]
```

Hope this will help someone. It took me a while to understand how these requests actualy work.

Comment: Hi, How to deal with: `{"error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "code": 403, "error_message": "You are not a sandbox user of this client"}` I want to show it using ajax call. Is that possible?